# How to assign elements of array to a pointer pointing to an allocated array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    int arr[3] = {10, 11, 12};
    int *p_arr = new int[3];
    *p_arr = *arr;  // This is how I assign, does not work
    std::cout << *(p_arr+1);  // Not results 11
}
```

I want to avoid the pointer pointing to the static array so I would assign or copy the static array elements to new allocated array. Is there a way to do this directly without iteratively assign it?

Comment: What does your C++ book say about this?

Comment: I have no idea. I used no book references. Mostly I teach myself online. I am doing self project right now.

Comment: _"I want to avoid pointing to the array."_ -- what is this supposed to mean?

Comment: ```p_array = arr``` i supposed

Comment: @NabilAsykar you want `p_arr` to contain the contents of `arr` but you don't want to invoke `std::copy` to achieve that? Is that your question?

Comment: @nick no. I don't want the pointer pointing to the static array. But actually you gave me a step forward. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually someone in the comment, [nick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9176689/nick), helped me answer. `std::copy` might be the answer. Even though it still uses an iterative way, still better to use it rather than creating the code.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int arr[3] = {0, 1, 2};
    int *p_arr = new int[3];
    int length = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int);
    std::copy(arr+0, arr+length, p_arr+0);  // Copy elements
    cout << sizeof(arr[0])/sizeof(int) << endl << *(p_arr+2);
}
```

Comment: use a vector instead :3

Comment: Technically, this does not answer the question. The question states *"without iteratively assign it"*, and `std::copy` iteratively assigns elements. Please try to say what you mean in your questions, or you'll miss out on potential answers.